# how do i uninstall an app in mountain lion?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to uninstall MAMP and MAMP pro from my mountain lion macbook and don't know how i should do that. I tried dragging the icon from my launchpad to the Trash, but it doesn't work.
What should i do?

Comment: read the question wrong the first time - just updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

MAMP has a specific uninstaller in the disk image you installed with. Mount that disk image and you should see the uninstaller. Go [here](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/installation/uninstall) for more information.

For the rest of your apps that don't have specific uninstallers, use AppZapper, which is a nice utility. There are a few alternatives (CleanMyMac has a built in function for this) http://www.appzapper.com/

Comment: i trashed the disk image, of course :) i'll try appZapper

Comment: I would advise against using AppZapper if it's got an uninstaller built for it. Try Applications/MAMP Pro/... and see if the uninstaller is there.

Comment: actually there is the uninstaller, but if i try to do use that, after inserting the password i get "Error - the privileged action failed"

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Applications (it should be in the sidebar of the Finder) and drag the app into the trash from there.

Comment: ok i had used a mac with 10.6.8 and i was wondering where the hell the Application folder had gone :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with uninstalling MAMP; I found a blog post that details what you need to do to fully uninstall MAMP [here](http://pivotwebdesign.com/blog/?p=34) which refers to a Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058768)